# Is there a way to switch between or reset role based credentials using `okta-aws` command line utility?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli, credentials, okta

Going through [Okta's github repo](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-aws-cli-assume-role) it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to switch between AWS roles using their command line utility.

Normally I get temporary credentials using `okta-aws default sts get-caller-identity`. If I'm switching between projects and need to likewise switch my temporary credentials to a different role, the best method I've found thus far is to delete two files, `~/.okta/profile` & `~/.okta/.current-session`, then re-run the above command.

I've also found that when `OKTA_STS_DURATION` in `.okta/config.properties` is set for longer than is configured for that AWS role, you either need to wait until the local duration setting expires or reset the credentials process using the same method as above.

**Is there a way to switch between or reset role based credentials using `okta-aws` command line utility?**

Note: I'm using role as interchangeable with profile -- please correct me if this is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

At this point the best solution is to switch over to [gimme-aws-creds](https://github.com/Nike-Inc/gimme-aws-creds). After you run through the setup it ends up being easier to use, and appears to be better maintained by Nike.